# Select * and one more column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to do something like this :

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT @row_number := 1 as row_number,* FROM `users`;
```

What I need is :
`*` + `row_number`

Above statement gets me an error about `*`.

If I replace all columns name instead of `*` it works fine.

Like so :

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT @row_number := 1 as row_number,Id, Name,UserName,LastName FROM `users`;
```

But I don't want to type all columns name.

Is there any solution?

Comment: You should use a table alias before the `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell MySQL what table you're referring to when you say `*`.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT @row_number := 1 as row_number, `users`.* FROM `users`;
```

Alternatively, you could switch around the `@row_number` and `*`.

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT *, @row_number := 1 as row_number FROM `users`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SET @row_number = 0;
SELECT @row_number := 1 as row_number,`users`.* FROM `users`;
```